# Ruby Rails update an attribute into new database table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I migrated a new database table here it looks like this:

```
  create_table "books", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "books_title"
    t.integer  "books_count"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
  end
```

and my **models/books.rb** looks like this:

```
class Books < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :books_count, :books_title
end
```

and i'm trying to create new record using this code:

```
<%= form_for(@Books) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :books_title, 'Book Title' %> 
  <%= f.text_field :books_title %>

<% end %>
```

then i'm getting error: `undefined method books_title for NilClass:Class`

also my **controllers/books_controller.rb** looks like this:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
end
```

Please help me.I'm very new to ruby, what shoud I do what command i need to run? Thanks!

Comment: its actually "@books" not "@Books" and I dont see this line in your controller, "@books = Books.all"(actually, it should be book, model names are singular and table names are plural).. welcome to rails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually "@books" not "@Books" 
and I dont see this line in your controller, "@books = Books.all"
(actually, it should be book, model names are singular and table names are plural)..

Welcome to rails...

I would do this, goto your app path and type,

```
rails g scaffold book title:string count:integer user_id:integer
```

The above command will generate everything for you from routes, model, migration, controller, view to test cases.

Need not worry about anything. Just

run `rake db:migrate` (it would probably throw an error since you already have "books" table, drop it)

Now visit, `http://localhost:3000/books`, you will see the books list(index view). Now, goto your books controller and start your learning method by method.

Comment: Thanks! how do I show http://localhost:3000/books results to another pages? getting error when i use this <%= @book.title %> i grabbed from show.html.erb

Comment: like on http://localhost:3000/users/1/account mby i need to add something like 'belongs_to :user'? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Enter here......http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/12390/welcome-johny-derp?tab=general

Answer (score 0):

You must create @book instance for `form_for` method like this.

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end 
end
```

And view.

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :books_title, 'Book Title' %> 
  <%= f.text_field :books_title %>

<% end %>
```

And you must have `create` method in your books controller.

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def create
    @book = Book.create(book_params)
  end 
  private 
  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:books_title)
  end
end
```

I recommend you to use `:title` instead of `:books_title`. Because it's a little redundant.

Answer (score 0):

> also my controllers/books_controller.rb looks like this:
>
> class StocksController < ApplicationController
> end

Rails has a naming convention, of using the same name for the file as for the controller, so you should either rename `StocksController` to `BooksController` or `books_controller.rb` to `stocks_controller`.

In any case, you are going to need an action in it, that initializes the book object for the form. And a create action, to save it. Another thing, it's standard to name your variable as a lowercase variable, and in singular, so it would be `@book`.

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end 

  def create
    @book = Book.create(params)
  end 
end
```

And update your form to be

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :books_title, 'Book Title' %> 
  <%= f.text_field :books_title %>

<% end %>
```